# How to handle multiple chat sessions with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am currently developing a chat system using Node.js. My question is, how do I handle multiple chat sessions with Node.js. That's a bit vague so I'll explain...

So for example two people might engage in a chat session. Node.js checks every couple of seconds for new messages. This is simple enough as I can get this to work fine using my code below.

My issue is when another two people at the same time are in another chat session.

At present I am sending two query strings called "chat_id" and "check_date" so it can check for new chat messages after a certain date and time.

Problem is, the "chat_id" and "check_date" are overwritten every time a new chat is started because the server is being used by both chat rooms.

Am I making sense?

My code below:

```
var chat_id, check_date;

var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http"),  
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    fs = require("fs"),  
    events = require("events");  

// Conntect to database
var Client = require('mysql').Client;
var client = new Client();
client.host = 'localhost';
client.port = 3306;
client.database = '****';
client.user = '****';
client.password = '****';
client.connect(function(error, results) {
  if(error) {
    console.log('Connection Error: ' + error.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL');
});

// Check for chat updates
function getChatUpdates() {  

    if (typeof(check_date) == 'undefined')
        return;

    client.query('SELECT name, message FROM chat WHERE chat_id = "' + chat_id + '" AND date_entered > "' + check_date + '"', 
    function selectCb(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('GetData Error: ' + error.message);
            client.end();
            return;
        }

        if (results.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0;i<results.length;i++) {
                console.log('Name: ' + results[i]['name']);
                console.log('Message: ' + results[i]['message']);
            }
        }

  });

}  

// Set interval to check for chat updates every 2 seconds
setInterval(getChatUpdates, 2000);  

http.createServer(function(request, response) {  

    // Get the query strings
    var uri = url.parse(request.url, true);  
    chat_id = uri.query.chat_id;
    check_date = uri.query.check_date;
    console.log('Chat ID: ' + chat_id);
    console.log('Last Check: ' + check_date);

    // we'll do something here later.

}).listen(8080);  

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are having a PHP background and when programming in node.js you should have a completely different mindset. You should not poll(`setInterval(getChatUpdates, 2000);`
) for messages, but push(callbacks/events) messages to users on event. I advice you to have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io) and use a in-memory database like [redis](http://redis.io)(instead of mysql) to store your messages. When you code like this your site will perform much better and is going to be real-time(more). Also I would advice you to use [express](http://expressjs.com/) as your framework to develop websites instead of using raw `http` module. I don't know if you already  know about [npm](http://npmjs.org), but you should use that to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Great! I am still wanting to store in MySQL as well so I can access the chat messages from PHP. Is it easy enough to use multiple data storages so that NodeJS works more effectively? Any further suggestions? Other than that, your response helps a lot!

Comment: @Ben you can and should probably also use redis from PHP using predis, especially when you want to store chat messages, because redis is very fast product => https://github.com/nrk/predis/

Answer (score 4):

> var chat_id, check_date;

Are global variables. You are going to be overriding the `chat_id` on every connection (in `createServer`. You probably need some sort of session storage (to associate a user and their chat) eg. an Array, Redis, etc.

Comment: Awesome, that gives some guidance :) Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you trying to use MySQL as message queue. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)?